# How to show step increment bar by default in a number input with CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css

Lets say I have an input like [this:](https://jsfiddle.net/6zmpLrjg/)

```
<input type="number" step="1">
```

When you hover over the textbox, a scrollbar appears in the right of the number input.  How can I make this always visible?

Comment: How can you have the scrollbar shown by default? And by textbox I assume you mean the number input, right?

Comment: by scrollbar I mean the increment thing that pops up on the right of the number input when you use the "step" attribute.  And yeah I mean number input.

Comment: it is inaccurate! the default view depends on the browser.
On FireFox it is present / not with chrome; There is no rule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
input::-webkit-inner-spin-button {
 opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<input type="number" step="1">
```